# BIRT (Eclipse BIRT) - Date format in Runtime and Designer version differ

Tags: eclipse, birt

I'm using Eclispse BIRT version 4.7.0 to run reports in various formats,

My report has a date field in the following format: 'DD/MM/YYYY/'

When I run the report through the Eclipse BIRT Designer application, with the WebViewer, or to PDF for example, the date comes printed in the expected format, for example it prints '05/07/2006'

But when I run the report using the Runtime Engine (via command line) it prints the same date value like this: 'Jul, 5, 2006'

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Select the data, on the properties, go in "Format DateTime", is it "Unformatted"? 
-> if yes, then format like you want : '05/07/2006' and Locale english (US)

Comment: You mean in the Designer version right? My problem is that in the Runtime version it doesn't come like I want it, which is '05/07/2006', like it already is in the Designer version